# Haystack more like this ignores filters

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

When I chain a filter before my more_like_this call on SearchQuerySet, the filter doesn't seem to be applied at all.

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet as sqs
from articles.models import Article

article = Article.objects.get(pk=4560) # Article instance of one of the many articles I have
sqs().filter(author='testest@testtest.com').count() # 147 - 147 documents with author=testest@testtest.com... so far so good
sqs().more_like_this(article).count() #54893
sqs().filter(author='testest@testtest.com').more_like_this(article).count() # 54893!!!
```

I assumed doing:

```
sqs().filter(author='testest@testtest.com').more_like_this(article)
```

would limit my MLT search within the 147 filtered documents, but it's almost as if the filter is being completely ignored.

I also tried reversing the order of the chain:

```
sqs().more_like_this(article).filter(author='testest@testtest.com')
```

but it ends up with returning the entire search index

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Here's my article_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.body.excerpt|striptags|escape }}
```

search_index.py

```
class ArticleIndexes(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True, boost=1.1)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='author')
    site_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='site_id')
    # non-indexed, stored field
    stored_obj = ArticleStorageField(indexed=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem long time ago - filtering with more like this is just not implemented in haystacks elasticsearch backend.
I've made pull request to both pyelasticsearch and haystack to make it work. Pyelasticsearch allows it now, but haystack still have no support (and I've closed my pull request).

This commit fixes it in haystack:
https://github.com/jasisz/django-haystack/commit/76473d8eebf49a0fffba025993a533b852aa8578